# ArcGIS Pro Topology - Fix multiple errors in one step through Inspector

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology

Does someone know if it is possible to select multiple "error-features" in ArcGIS Pro Topology error inspector and fix all of them with the same solution (e.g. create new feature)?  Currently in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 it does not seem possible.[image]

Comment: I managed to fix multiple errors at once, but for the must not overlap topology. I do not remember exactly, but the procces was something like, create new features for all errors and merge adjoining polygons to the nearest one, while only the newly created features are selected. My project was about digitizing a large old map with roughly 7k polygons where 10 meters to the right or left was not an issue. If this fits you I could dig up the project and help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 this is not possible; each error must be addressed individually.

It also appears you've added a suggested idea to the ArcGIS Idea site (based on the same screen shot):  https://community.esri.com/ideas/15760-arcgis-pro-topology-inpector-fix-multiple

Comment: Hi! Yes - i also adressed it to ESRI to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to fix multiple errors at once using the **Fix** tab:

[image]

This has existed in ArcGIS Pro since version 1.4. The workflow is documented here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/validate-and-fix-geodatabase-topology.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5ED07CFE7FCE4182A1334B7C249922D1

The fix tab was not available in ArcMap. In ArcMap, you had to make sure you were selecting errors of the same type in order to have the choice to fix multiple errors at once via the context menu.